# React Component doesn't trigger onClick

Tags: reactjs

I have a React `button` component that won't trigger the `onClick` event when clicked. I added an `:active` CSS selector to make sure it was enabled and clickable. weird thing is, an `onChange` handler on an `input` right next to it works fine. Any thoughts?

```
return (
  <ul className="horizontal">
    <li className="adjustInput">
      <label>
        <input max={200} min={10} onChange={e => actions.onAdjustSize(e.target.value)} type="range" value={size} />
        Image Size: {size}%
      </label>
    </li>
    <li className="adjustInput">
      <label>
        <input max={OPACITY_MULTIPLIER} min={OPACITY_MULTIPLIER / 10} onChange={e => {actions.onAdjustOpacity(e.target.value / OPACITY_MULTIPLIER)}} type="range" value={opacity} />
        Opacity: {opacity}%
      </label>
    </li>
    <li className="adjustInput">
      <label>
        {/* This onChange is fired when I type in the input */}
        <input onChange={actions.onRemove} type="text" />
        {/* This onClick isn't fired no matter what I try */}
        <button onClick={actions.onRemove}>Remove</button>
      </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
);
```

[Image of UI rendered by code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/karM4.png)

I've obviously tried clicking the button with the mouse. I've also tried tabbing to it and pressing the spacebar & enter. Manually triggering a click in JS. Nothing seems to work :/

Comment: Do you really need to put the button into the same label element with input?

Comment: Can you right click and inspect the `button` and see what attributes it has in a browser (like Chrome)?

Comment: that component is rendered in a dropdown. I just tried removing it from the dropdown and it works then

Comment: @raina77ow - I just did that to test. the button can be anywhere in the component.

Comment: @PhilipTzou - it has no attributes at all, which is the same as all the comnponents

Comment: See, a label is usually associated with a single form control, so that clicking the label activates the corresponding input. That might mess the things in your case.

Comment: thanks for the suggest @raina77ow. for some reason that event handler just isn't attaching no matter what I try. I'm just doing it manually when the component mounts. thanks for the suggestions!